# Proxychains not working when I added proxies. I don't want to use tor., I just want to use my proxies

Tags: linux, proxy, kali-linux, privacy, parrot-os

I'm trying to use proxychains which kept throwing this error

```
$ proxychains firefox www.startpage.com 
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| location.services.mozilla.com

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: location.services.mozilla.com does not exist
|DNS-request| location.services.mozilla.com

Similar errors....

!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-response|: firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com does not exist
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm
Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs
```

But my proxychains config file (/etc/proxychains.conf) is pretty much in correct format which is like below

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...

https   xx.xx.xx.xx     80
https   xx.x.x.xx       8080
https   xx.xx.x.xxx     80
(A lot of proxies like above)

# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
#socks4         127.0.0.1 9050
```

But it still works in case of tor connection. Still won't work when I add proxies. I've tried different proxies from different websites which provides free proxies each with 100+ entries but none of them didn't work.

Also my DNS server is working fine as I checked my resolv.conf and its service is also working properly.

My OS is up-to-date Parrot OS with all packages also up to date.

Comment: Hello @dicaprio, I'm working on a socks5 transparent proxy which has a proxy-chain option. https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp It works pretty well on mac/*bsd machines, but I lack Linux based configurations. If you find it interesting, you can try TS-Warp as well and share your experience.